# Select First Created Child For Parent

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to select the first `quote` that a `contact` has created to modify it yet I'm not quite sure how to do so and I've been trying for a while. The SQL tables look like this:

```
quotes

id | name | value | date_entered

contacts

id | first_name | last_name | notes

quotes_contacts

id | quote_id | contact_id
```

So I want to get a list of all of the quotes that where created first for a contact if that makes any sense so we can list each customers first quote.

I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    c.first_name,
    c.last_name,
    (
        SELECT value 
        FROM quotes q 
        LEFT JOIN quotes_contacts qc ON q.id = qc.quote_id
        WHERE qc.contact_id = c.id
        ORDER BY q.date_entered
        LIMIT 1
    ) first_quote_value
FROM
    contacts c
```

will get you their first quote for each contact.